# How to change ASP .NET WebForms ReportViewer control print to local printer no PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, reportviewer, sqlreportingservice

I have a report RDLC with SQL Reporting Services in ASP .NET WebForms, but Print Button in ReportViewer web control only allows to create PDF file? How could I change to default local printer or show printer local list?

[image]